# Hide price element from web page using Greasemonkey/JQuery

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I am trying to hide the price element from this CSS path using Greasemonkey.

```
html body div#__nuxt div#__layout div.lv-default-layout.-header-is-immersive main#main.lv-default-layout__content div.lv-category div.lv-paginated-list.lv-product-list ul.lv-list.lv-product-list__items li#lv-card-M46279.lv-product-list__item div.lv-product-card.-has-mini-slider.-full-bleed.-default-variant div.lv-product-card__wrap div.lv-product-card__info-wrapper div.lv-product-card__info div.lv-price.lv-product-card__price.body-xs
```

Based on other SO answers I wrote the following Greasemonkey script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        hide-LV-prices
// @include     https://ap.louisvuitton.com/*
// @description Hides prices on Louis Vuitton page  
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

$(".lv-product-card__price.body-xs").hide()
```

but prices are still being displayed. Original URL is https://ap.louisvuitton.com/eng-sg/bags/for-women/all-handbags/_/N-t1rrahxp. HTML example is:

```
<div class="lv-price lv-product-card__price body-xs"><!----> 
<span class="notranslate">S$ 5,500.00</span> <!---->
</div>
```

Comment: Post your relevant HTML as well. Other wise it's guessing game :)

Comment: @4b0 good point, edited post to add URL.

Comment: It happens because the element is added after your script runs so jQuery hides an array of zero elements. You can debug it yourself in devtools. The solution is to remove jQuery and use GM_addStyle('.lv-product-card__price.body-xs { display: none !important }')

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript code makes changes at the time it runs. On the other hand CSS rules make changes at the time they are added and from then on (unless overwritten).

As mentioned by wOxxOm, CSS will be applied to elements that are created later on.

Here is a sample userscript to work on.

**Note**
`GM_addStyle/GM.addStyle` are not supported in the current GM4.
`GM_addStyle/GM.addStyle` are supported in FireMonkey, Tampermonkey, & Violentmonkey.

```html
<div class="lv-price lv-product-card__price body-xs"><!----> 
  <span class="notranslate">S$ 5,500.00</span> <!---->
</div>
```

#### FireMonkey, Tampermonkey, Violentmonkey

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          hide-LV-prices
// @include       https://ap.louisvuitton.com/*
// @description   Hides prices on Louis Vuitton page  
// @grant         GM.addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

const css = 
`.lv-product-card__price.body-xs {
  display: none !important;
}`;

GM_addStyle(css);
```

#### Greasemonkey

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          hide-LV-prices
// @include       https://ap.louisvuitton.com/*
// @description   Hides prices on Louis Vuitton page  
// @grant         GM.addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM.addStyle = (css) => {
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.textContent = css;
  (document.head || document.body).appendChild(style);
};

const css = 
`.lv-product-card__price.body-xs {
  display: none !important;
}`;

GM_addStyle(css);
```

You can also make a userscript for all userscript managers.

#### FireMonkey, Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey, Violentmonkey

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          hide-LV-prices
// @include       https://ap.louisvuitton.com/*
// @description   Hides prices on Louis Vuitton page  
// @grant         GM.addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

// check if GM.addStyle is supported
if (typeof GM.addStyle !== 'function') {
  // define GM.addStyle
  GM.addStyle = (css) => {
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.textContent = css;
    (document.head || document.body).appendChild(style);
  };
}

const css = 
`.lv-product-card__price.body-xs {
  display: none !important;
}`;

GM_addStyle(css);
```